# Javascript show/hide video controls on mouse activity

Tags: javascript, html5-video

I'm facing issues to make a customized video controller when I'm adding some code to hide the controller after a while.

The videoControls is placed over the video, with same width, and at the bottom of it (as any video media).

The behavior is conform to expected if the mouse is over the videoElement (ie. videoControls is hidden if the mouse leaves the area, or if the mouse doesn't move for 3sec).
The same is true if the mouse enters the videoControls area without being on the videoElement area before.
The issue fires when the mouse passes over the videoElement and then goes to the videoControls, the videoControls is hidden quite immediately and I can't catch why. So I'll be pleased if you can find my mistake or explain me why this way is not suitable for this feature. :)

This code is for a project where only vanilla JS is allowed. Plus, I don't want to use the native HTML5 video controls as I need to have enhanced keyboard navigation features for accessibility (not well suitable according to MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Accessibility/Multimedia)

here is the HTML of this part of the page :

```
<div class="lightbox">
  <video class="lightbox__media" src="./public/img/media/243/full/Animals_Wild_Horses_in_the_mountains.mp4">here is alt text</video>
  <div class="lightbox__videocontrols" style="width: 1049.38px; margin: 0px 94.005px; bottom: 85px; display: flex; opacity: 0; z-index: -1;">
    <button class="lightbox__videocontrols__playpause lightbox__videocontrols__button" aria-label="Lecture.">
      <img src="public/img/icon/play.svg" alt="Lecture">
    </button>
    <button class="lightbox__videocontrols__stop lightbox__videocontrols__button" aria-label="Arrêt.">
      <img src="public/img/icon/stop.svg" alt="Arrêt">
    </button>
    <button class="lightbox__videocontrols__rwd lightbox__videocontrols__button" aria-label="Recule de 3 secondes.">
      <img src="public/img/icon/reverse.svg" alt="Avance 3 secondes">
    </button>
    <button class="lightbox__videocontrols__fwd lightbox__videocontrols__button" aria-label="Avance de 3 secondes">
      <img src="public/img/icon/forward.svg" alt="Retour 3 secondes">
    </button>
    <div class="lightbox__videocontrols__time lightbox__videocontrols__button" tabindex="0" role="status">0:00/0:16</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and here is the js code :

```
const videoElement = document.querySelector(".lightbox__media");
const videoControls = document.querySelector(".lightbox__videocontrols");
videoElement.addEventListener("mouseleave", function () {
  hideVideoControls();
  if (controlsTimeout) {
    clearTimeout(controlsTimeout);
    controlsTimeout = null;
  }
});
videoControls.addEventListener("mouseleave", function () {
  hideVideoControls();
  if (controlsTimeout) {
    clearTimeout(controlsTimeout);
    controlsTimeout = null;
  }
});

videoControls.addEventListener("mouseover", function () {
  showVideoControls();
  resetTimeout();
  videoControls.addEventListener ("mousemove", function () {
    showVideoControls();
    resetTimeout();
  });
});

function showVideoControls() {
  videoControls.style.opacity = 1;
  videoControls.style.zIndex = 100;
}

function hideVideoControls() {
  videoControls.style.opacity = 0;
  setTimeout(function () {
    videoControls.style.zIndex = -1;
  }, 400); // after opacitiy transition
}

function resetTimeout() {
  if (controlsTimeout) {
    clearTimeout(controlsTimeout);
    controlsTimeout = null;
  }
  controlsTimeout = setTimeout(hideVideoControls, 3000);
}
```

EDIT 2021/02/26: I didn't find any fix with this method, so I add a tracker on the mouse to get the position at each time, and I compare with the video position area (using getComputedStyle). It works whatever the mouse is actually over the video, the div, or the control buttons.

So the issue is solved, but I still do not understand what was wrong this the first attempt.

Comment: Why is the mouseover/mousemove listener combination duplicated?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, it's a copy/paste error, I'm removing the second one ^^